# how to create a first vue js project

Tags: vue.js

I just started with vue.js. I created a simple project but it is not working.Please check what is wrong in the above code. I totally new to this I don't know what I have made mistake in this.

thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="root">
        <input type="text" v-model="name">

        <p>Hi my name is: {{ name }}</p>

</div>



<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script>


    new vue({

        el: '#root',
        data: {
            name: 'Matheen'

        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no I am not getting the output

Comment: I am getting output like this {{ name }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `new vue({` line. `Vue` should start with a capital V.

Comment: @matheenulla If that was your issue, you should strongly consider getting familiar with your browser's error console. It will have been showing something along the lines of "ReferenceError: vue is not defined" that would help in debugging.

Comment: @ceejayoz this was my issue. Now I am installing vue devtools to get errors

Comment: Why exactly was my answer downvoted?

Comment: @MattU Drive-by random downvotes happen all the time.